# Web services and Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I recently created a web service which all worked fine until I moved it from my local PC to our development server. I now get a `HTTP status 401: Access Denied` message when I try to connect from a small test website.  I googled around and found the following code:

```
SoiisdevJobService.JobsService jService = new SoiisdevJobService.JobsService();
jService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

And it now works, but I'm not sure what this code actually does. Can someone explain it to me? I'm using IIS 6, Windows auth, and in my config I've set the auth mode to Windows and to deny non-authed users. In my small test app I've set the same in my config.

Why do I need to provide the code above? I expected this to just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have turned off access for non-authenticated users. See the quote below from the Microsoft website (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811318/EN-US):

> When Anonymous access authentication is turned off for the Web service
>   application, all the caller applications must provide the credentials
>   before making any request. By default, the Web service client proxy
>   does not inherit the credentials of the security context where the Web
>   service client application is running.

Comment: Excellent thanks.  What are the defaultcredentials though?  Is it simply assigning my windows logon to the webservice to use as authentication